# What happened to the org.jgroups.ChannelException class?

Tags: java, jgroups

Trying to migrate a very old jboss project to the new jre / jboss versions. Cannot find class `ChannelException` in the new jar files, even documentation for such old classes can hardly be found. Looks like this class (and its descendants, eg `ChannelClosedException`, `ChannelNotConnectedException`) is completely dropped. From what I can comprehend, this exception was thrown from certain jgroup classes' constructors, like `JChannel`; in the newer version these now throw a `java.lang.Exception`.

So, what should I do? Would it be OK to just use `java.lang.Exception` in its place? Or it can still be found in some package?